# Not sure why data is not rendering out as expected

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am trying to render some data out with local JSON file supplied in the src folder, following is the source code I am using and the screenshot attached too. I have tried doing the console.log and it shows that item is empty in the Chrome console area, please let me know where I might have gone wrong with the following code, thank you so much.

[image: iOS Screenshot]

```
    // import dependencies here
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, Dimensions, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
    import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

    // import screens here

    // import components here

    import servicesData from '../components/servicesData.json';

    const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

    export default class Services extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={servicesData}
              renderItem={(item) =>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                  <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage} source={{ uri: item.image }} >
                    <View style={styles.overlay}>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.excerpt}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
                      <Icon name="arrow-right" type="font-awesome" size={30} color='#ffffff' />
                    </View>
                  </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              }
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      button: {
        // flex: 0.5,
      },
      overlay: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.6)',
        height: '100%'
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        width: width,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      title: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 25,
        paddingTop: 30,
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
      },
      excerpt: {
        padding: 20,
        paddingRight: 20,
        fontSize: 18,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: '#ffffff',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for the input, but I found the issue. There was one set of curly braces missing in the supplied code, which were for the destructring. Following is the final piece of working code for me and might be helpful for others too;

```
    export default class Services extends Component {
          render() {
            return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                  data={servicesData}
                  renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                      <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage} source={{ uri: item.image }} >
                        <View style={styles.overlay}>
                          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.excerpt}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
                          <Icon name="arrow-right" type="font-awesome" size={30} color='#ffffff' />
                        </View>
                      </ImageBackground>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  }
                />
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing **curly braces** and **return** statement.

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={servicesData}
      renderItem={(item) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
            <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage} source={{ uri: 
            item.image }} >
              <View style={styles.overlay}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.excerpt}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
                <Icon name="arrow-right" type="font-awesome" size={30} color='#ffffff' />
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      }}
    />
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `renderItem` method like this.

```
renderItem={(info) => {
  const { item } = info;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                  <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage} source={{ uri: item.image }} >
                    <View style={styles.overlay}>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.excerpt}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
                      <Icon name="arrow-right" type="font-awesome" size={30} color='#ffffff' />
                    </View>
                  </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
);
}}
```

or like this.

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                  <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundImage} source={{ uri: item.image }} >
                    <View style={styles.overlay}>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                      <Text style={styles.excerpt}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
                      <Icon name="arrow-right" type="font-awesome" size={30} color='#ffffff' />
                    </View>
                  </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.